# Facebook Connect: what type of user profile information can be retrieved?

Tags: facebook

When enabling Facebook Connect, any facebook user can then login to your website,

what type of user profile information can my website retrieve?

Username?
Email?
First Name?
Last Name?

Answer (score 1):

Khou,

There are seriously loads of API docs around.

Good luck on your facebook journey ;)

Answer (score 1):

There is a ton of information you can retrieve, if the user has permitted it through their privacy settings. Just about everything you can retrieve is in a FQL table somewhere:
http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/FQL_Tables

You cannot, however, get their email. You need to ask permission, using the API, to do that. This is also not a data bonanza, you can only permanently store the user ID. Everything else you can only store for 24 hours, then need to re-query Facebook for the information.

If you just want to display the user's first and last name, you can use FBML rendered with the Facebook Connect code. 
http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/FBML

Comment: Isn't the username the email address? http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/User_(FQL)

(your able to retrieve the username).